# IE setting row height not working when using rowspan

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

Just wondering why the following HTML doesn't work. Basically when ever I set rowspan on a tables row, IE seems to ignore the the heights that i've set:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td height="20">A</td>
    <td align="center" rowspan="3">
      Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="20">B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Does anyone know why its behaving this way?

Comment: I believe if you have to use tables, having two main cells and then putting a table with three rows (one cell in each) in the left cell of the main table will make more sense. You can set heights of the rows for the second table as you wish.

Comment: I thought about this but the users need to be able to copy an paste from the table into word/excel and it just work... Hence having nested tables/divs in cells isn't really an option... :(

Answer (score 2):

I believe what is happening here is that IE will spread the remaining space available in order to fill the height of the second TD in the first TR that spans all three rows.

Consider this example:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr height="30px">
    <td>
      A
    </td>
    <td align="center" rowspan="3">
      Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
      <br />Test
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="60px">
      B
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="100%">
      C
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here we see that IE renders properly because 60px + 30px = < total height of second column so we tell the final td to be height 100% in order take whatever space is leftover so IE doesn't spread it across the rows.

I tried a few different test cases and that seemed to prove out.  First to admit though I could be wrong.

Comment: I noticed that B doesn't render the correct height which is probably to be expected... weird thing is that this doesn't work if you just rowspan over 2 cells - the third *must* be added.

Comment: Turns out it just doesn't work anyway... I just get the same thing over and over no matter what is where. The example you gave also doesn't work, as the first row has a height of 56 pixels, the second is 75 pixels. Ho hum.