# TD height expands on dynamic content in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

First; I've searched for this here and on the net, but couldn't find a working solution. I'm working on this problem literally for two days now, so I have to ask.

I've following problem :

```
    <table width="650px" border="1" >
    <tr>
        <td style="height :5px">stay as you are</td>
        <td rowspan="3" id="content">
            empty
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height :5px">please dont expand</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background: red;height : 100%;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="do" onclick="dontExpand()">
<script language="Javascript">
    function dontExpand() {
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            html += "lorem ipsum<br>";
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = html;
    }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle example of the problem, works only in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/3xSRu/)

The upper left and the left cell in the middle are expanding after the content dynamically gets modified by Javascript.

I guess it does have something to do with the DocTypes, but I'm no expert.

Is there a way of making Internet Explorer and Firefox to only expand the lower left cell; the other two cells above should stay as they are.

Need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here same problem: [IE setting row height not working when using rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461528/ie-setting-row-height-not-working-when-using-rowspan)

I guess one solution will be to change teh height of the last table col after you update the content based on the total height after adding content - 10 px ?

Comment: any idea on how to get the height of the table after the content is added dynamically ? I've tried document.getElementById("content").style.height and variants but couldnt make it work.

Comment: Solved :

I couldnt determine the height after the content added with pure Javascript. So I used jquery instead :

$("#theRed").css("height", $("#content").height() - 10);

('theRed' is the ID of the lower left cell.)

Thanks a lot, Techmonk !

Answer (score 0):

So the first two cells have to be only 5px tall? On FF it works if you remove the height:100% from the third td.

EDIT: OK form me it kinda works if instead of 100% i write height:640px on the last div. Since you know that the total height of the table is 650px then it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Indeed, I removed as you said the 100% height and it works in FF as well. Bu IE problem is still there.

Comment: it works for me on ie9 by setting the three divs with 5px, 5px and 640px

Comment: but 640 is the width of the table, not important in this example actually. since the content (lorem ipsum) is filled by Ajax and I dont know the quantity of the data, I can't know the exact height of the table in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
var height = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight; // to determine the content height.
table.style.height = height + 10 + "px";
```

Further do this only for IE as remove the height:100% works in other browsers