# How to prevent IE from minimizing empty table cells' height?

Tags: html, html-table, cell

Please refer to the following code.

Firefox and Google Chrome's renderings are exactly what I want, that Cell 1 and 2 maintain a fixed height, and Cell 4 and 5 (empty cells) change height according to Cell 3's height.

However, IE is minimizing Cell 4 and 5's height. That's not what I want.

Is there a way to make IE behaves like Firefox and Google Chrome?

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td height="40">Cell 1</td>
  <td height="40">Cell 2</td>
  <td rowspan="2">Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3<br>Cell 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE setting row height not working when using rowspan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461528/ie-setting-row-height-not-working-when-using-rowspan)

Answer (score 0):

What would happen if you modify your empty

```
<td>
```

to be

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

put a space in the cell...

Comment: Thanks. But even with `&nbsp;`, IE is still minimizing Cell 4 and 5's height.